# Creating increasing and decreasing order option in the same priority queue?

Tags: c++

I created a priority queue as given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Time {
    int h; // >= 0
    int m; // 0-59
    int s; // 0-59
};

class CompareTime {
public:
    bool operator()(Time& t1, Time& t2)
    {
       if (t1.h < t2.h) return true;
       if (t1.h == t2.h && t1.m < t2.m) return true;
       if (t1.h == t2.h && t1.m == t2.m && t1.s < t2.s) return true;
       return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
int order;
cout<<"Enter whether you want to create the priority queue in increasing or decreasing order";
cin>>order;

    priority_queue<Time, vector<Time>, CompareTime> pq;

    // Array of 4 time objects:

    Time t[4] = { {3, 2, 40}, {3, 2, 26}, {5, 16, 13}, {5, 14, 20}};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
       pq.push(t[i]);
    while (! pq.empty()) {
       Time t2 = pq.top();
       cout << setw(3) << t2.h << " " << setw(3) << t2.m << " " <<
       setw(3) << t2.s << endl;
       pq.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This priority queue orders in increasing order of time. Now I want to give the user the option of whether he wants to order according to increasing time or decreasing time at run time -- as is shown in the example. According to the choice provided by the user I want to order my priority queue either in increasing order or decreasing order. Do I have to create a separate priority queue and CompareTime class for the same. Or is it possible to incorporate this functionality using the present data structures?

I am using gcc version: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Comment: A sneaky solution to this would be to negate each element that goes into the heap, and negate it again when you take it off the top.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a nice answer to this. (Obviously, `std::priority_queue` is not exactly the best data structure to handle this task. I would recommend using `std::vector` and sorting it.) One possible solution involving the priority queue is:

```
class CompareTimeInverse {
public:
    bool operator()(Time& t1, Time& t2)
    {
        CompareTime c;
        return !c(t1, t2);
    }
};

template<typename C>
void impl(Time* t, std::size_t t_sz)
{
    priority_queue<Time, vector<Time>, C> pq;

    for (int i = 0; i < t_sz; ++i)
        pq.push(t[i]);

    while (! pq.empty()) {
        Time t2 = pq.top();
        cout << setw(3) << t2.h << " " << setw(3) << t2.m << " " <<
        setw(3) << t2.s << endl;
        pq.pop();
    }
}

int main()
{
    int order;
    cout<<"Enter whether you want to create the priority queue in increasing or decreasing order";
    cin>>order;

    // Array of 4 time objects:
    Time t[4] = { {3, 2, 40}, {3, 2, 26}, {5, 16, 13}, {5, 14, 20}};

    if (order == 0) {
        impl<CompareTime>(t, 4);
    }
    else if (order == 1) {
        impl<CompareTimeInverse>(t, 4);
    }

    return 0;
}
```